# Using javascript to render svg in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, svg

I have a few svg files and some .js files. 
I'd like to render the svg files using the .js files.

What I have done now is:
1. Put all the svg and js files into assets
2. And written this code:

```
    final String mimeType = "text/html"; 
    final String encoding = "utf-8"; 
    final String html = "<p><img height=\"600px\" width=\"600px \"src=\"file:///android_asset/drawing2.svg\" /></p>";



    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

The svg is shown. But the .js files have no effect at all. How do I make them work together? Any pointers / help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For security and privacy reasons javascript does not run in images in any browser. You'd have to use an `<object>`, `<embed>` or `<iframe>` tag to get scripting to work.